# Autorotation Button doesnt appear on GNOME on ubuntu 23.10

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, wayland, 23.10, canonical

Autorotation is working, at least for the moment in ubuntu 23.10 on wayland on gnome, when only worked only on x11(however is not working well since autorotation is only activated on wayland when the laptop is flip 360 degres, when on x11 the autorotation works even when the screen is in normal orientation,around 90 degrees).And if you go to the menu on the top rigth , the button for enabling and disabling the autorotation, the button is not there on wayland gnome.

is a way to tell devlopers and canonical to  fix this, and add the autorotation button on wayland gnome top panel, like it is on x11 gnome panel? and so will be avaiable on a future update?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)